# How to get clear filter x button inside filter textbox in ag grid angular6?

Tags: angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am trying to have clear filter x button inside filter textbox like below.I am using ag-grid version 17. I want something like,

- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
 |                                       x | 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -

Currently I am using below code but it is not showing as per requirement.
filterParams : {
          clearButton : true
}

Comment: are you using HTML <input type='number'> for filter ?

Comment: @ZulqarnainJalil here I am not asking to remove the x button. I want to add it in the textbox. You will have clear idea if you have worked on ag-grid angular.

Comment: @Basavaraj did you find a solution for this? I am looking for the same kind of workaround.